# a problem related with path lifting property

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

suppose finite $G$  acts freely on manifold $M$ ,where "freely" means that:$\forall m\in M,g_1\cdot m=g_2 \cdot m   \Leftrightarrow g_1=g_2$,

Define a relationship in $M$: if $m_1 \sim m_2$,which means that there exists $g \in G$ such that $m_1=g \cdot m_2$,then we can get a quotient space $M/G$

My problem is how to prove quotient maping :$p:M \rightarrow M/G$ has path lifting property and homotopy path lifting property

Comment: What is $G$?  This isn't true without some additional assumptions.

Comment: oh ,sorry ,it is  finite group

Comment: As $G$ is finite, the action is properly discontinuous, thus the quotient map is a covering map, and $M/G$ is a manifold. Thus the quotient map has both lifting properties.

Comment: why $M/G$ is a manifold ,so the quotient map has both lifting properties?

Comment: All of this is explained quite nicely in the book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by J.M. Lee, in chapter 21.

Comment: could you help more?